# Search array of nested objects with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, mapping, reduce

I have an array with objects. I'm trying to recursively search through them and create new array with modified key's.

The array:

```
    let response = {
    users: [
        {
            user_id: 1661871600,
            details: {
                height: 150,
                age: 33,
                work: 1015,
                school: 10,
                degree: 933
            },
            work: [
                {
                    id: 500,
                    main: 'Doctor',
                    description: 'Ofto',
                    icon: '10d',
                },
            ],
            look: {
                all: 100,
            },
            transport: {
                speed: 0.62,
                max_speed: 349,
            },
            visibility: 10000,
            hair: {
                type: 0.26,
            },
            date: '2022-08-30 15:00:00',
        },
        {
            user_id: 324235256,
            details: {
                height: 110,
                age: 25,
                work: 101,
                school: 110,
                degree: 553
            },
            work: [
                {
                    id: 500,
                    main: 'Software',
                    description: 'Programmer',
                    icon: '11d',
                },
            ],
            look: {
                all: 2,
            },
            transport: {
                speed: 1.2,
                max_speed: 49,
            },
            visibility: 221,
            hair: {
                type: 5.6,
            },
            date: '2021-01-30 12:00:00',
        },
        {
            user_id: 12353743,
            details: {
                height: 10,
                age: 75,
                work: 1,
                school: 114,
                degree: 3
            },
            work: [
                {
                    id: 500,
                    main: 'Pension',
                    description: 'Architect',
                    icon: '1d',
                },
            ],
            look: {
                all: 6,
            },
            transport: {
                speed: 3.2,
                max_speed: 29,
            },
            visibility: 21,
            hair: {
                type: 1.6,
            },
            date: '2020-01-30 12:00:00',
        },
    ],
};
```

I've tried using JSON.Stringify but I keep getting not desired result.

```
    function dynamic(obj, ...keyToFind) {
    const foundObj = {};
    const foundObjArray: any[] = [];
    keyToFind.forEach((key) => {
        JSON.stringify(obj, (_, nestedValue) => {
            if (nestedValue && nestedValue[a]) {
                foundObj[key] = nestedValue[a];
            }
            return nestedValue;
        });
        foundObjArray.push(foundObj);
    });
    return foundObjArray;
}
```

I'm calling this function with N number of parameters:

```
dynamic(response, 'age', 'work', 'main', 'description', 'type', 'date');
```

Once it is called I'm trying to construct a new array of objects who will look like:

```
let foundObjArray = [
   {
     'age': 33,
     'work': 1015,
     'main': 'Doctor',
     'description': 'Ofto',
     'type': 5.6,
     'date': '2022-08-30 15:00:00'
   },
   {
     'age': 25,
     'work': 101,
     'main': 'Software',
     'description': 'Programmer',
     'type': 0.26,
     'date': '2021-01-30 12:00:00'
   },
   .......
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JSON.stringify` based approach, as initially intended by the OP, is even a reliable one, in case one wants to target any user-item's first occurring entry regardless of its nesting level/depth where each property's value is not of object or array type itself.

One just needs to come up with an according property specific regex like e.g. for the `"work"` key ... [`/"work":(?<value>[^\[{]+?)(?=,"|\})/`](https://regex101.com/r/ss6jlt/1).

The rest then can be achieved by combined [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) tasks, where with each item's mapping a new object is created via reducing an array of property names which has to be provided as the `map` method's 2nd [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) parameter.

```js
const response = {
  users: [{
    user_id: 1661871600,
    details: {
      height: 150,
      age: 33,
      work: 1015,
      school: 10,
      degree: 933
    },
    work: [{
      id: 500,
      main: 'Doctor',
      description: 'Ofto',
      icon: '10d',
    }],
    look: {
      all: 100,
    },
    transport: {
      speed: 0.62,
      max_speed: 349,
    },
    visibility: 10000,
    hair: {
      type: 0.26,
    },
    date: '2022-08-30 15:00:00',
  }, {
    user_id: 324235256,
    details: {
      height: 110,
      age: 25,
      work: 101,
      school: 110,
      degree: 553
    },
    work: [{
      id: 500,
      main: 'Software',
      description: 'Programmer',
      icon: '11d',
    }],
    look: {
      all: 2,
    },
    transport: {
      speed: 1.2,
      max_speed: 49,
    },
    visibility: 221,
    hair: {
      type: 5.6,
    },
    date: '2021-01-30 12:00:00',
  }, {
    user_id: 12353743,
    details: {
      height: 10,
      age: 75,
      work: 1,
      school: 114,
      degree: 3
    },
    work: [{
      id: 500,
      main: 'Pension',
      description: 'Architect',
      icon: '1d',
    }],
    look: {
      all: 6,
    },
    transport: {
      speed: 3.2,
      max_speed: 29,
    },
    visibility: 21,
    hair: {
      type: 1.6,
    },
    date: '2020-01-30 12:00:00',
  }],
};

function createObjectOfFirstOccurringValuesFromBoundKeyList(item) {
  const itemData = JSON.stringify(item);
  return this // `this` equals the bound array of property names.
    .reduce((result, key) => {

      const { value = null } =
        RegExp(`"${ key }":(?<value>[^\[{]+?)(?=,"|\})`)
          // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/ss6jlt/1]
          .exec(itemData)
          ?.groups ?? {};

      if (value !== null) {
        Object
          .assign(result, { [key]: JSON.parse(value) });
      }
      return result;

    }, {})
}

const listOfFirstPropertyValueItems = response
  .users
  .map(createObjectOfFirstOccurringValuesFromBoundKeyList, [
    'age', 'work', 'main', 'description', 'type', 'date'
  ]);

console.log({
  listOfFirstPropertyValueItems
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let response = {
    users: [
        {
            user_id: 1661871600,
            details: {
                height: 150,
                age: 33,
                speed_min: 296.76,
                speed_max: 297.87,
                work: 1015,
                school: 10,
                degree: 933
            },
            work: [
                {
                    id: 500,
                    main: 'Doctor',
                    description: 'Ofto',
                    icon: '10d',
                },
            ],
            look: {
                all: 100,
            },
            transport: {
                speed: 0.62,
                max_speed: 349,
            },
            visibility: 10000,
            hair: {
                type: 0.26,
            },
            date: '2022-08-30 15:00:00',
        },
        {
            user_id: 324235256,
            details: {
                height: 110,
                age: 25,
                speed_min: 96.76,
                speed_max: 327.87,
                work: 101,
                school: 110,
                degree: 553
            },
            work: [
                {
                    id: 500,
                    main: 'Software',
                    description: 'Programmer',
                    icon: '11d',
                },
            ],
            look: {
                all: 2,
            },
            transport: {
                speed: 1.2,
                max_speed: 49,
            },
            visibility: 221,
            hair: {
                type: 5.6,
            },
            date: '2021-01-30 12:00:00',
        },
        {
            user_id: 12353743,
            details: {
                height: 10,
                age: 75,
                speed_min: 16.76,
                speed_max: 27.87,
                work: 1,
                school: 114,
                degree: 3
            },
            work: [
                {
                    id: 500,
                    main: 'Pension',
                    description: 'Architect',
                    icon: '1d',
                },
            ],
            look: {
                all: 6,
            },
            transport: {
                speed: 3.2,
                max_speed: 29,
            },
            visibility: 21,
            hair: {
                type: 1.6,
            },
            date: '2020-01-30 12:00:00',
        },
    ],
};

function getMatchedKey(arr, key) {
    let matched = arr.filter(x => key.endsWith(x));
    if(matched.length > 0) {
        return matched[0];
    }
}

function getLimitedData(data, requiredKey = []) {
    var result = {};
    function recurse(cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            let matchedKey = getMatchedKey(requiredKey, prop);
            matchedKey != undefined && (result[matchedKey] = cur);
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
            for (var i = 0, l = cur.length; i < l; i++)
                recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
            if (l == 0) {
                let matchedKey = getMatchedKey(requiredKey, prop);
                matchedKey != undefined && (result[matchedKey] = []);
            }
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop + "." + p : p);
            }
            if (isEmpty && prop) {
                let matchedKey = getMatchedKey(requiredKey, prop);
                matchedKey != undefined && (result[matchedKey] = {});
            }
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}

let keys = ['age', 'work', 'main', 'description', 'type', 'date'];
let output = response.users.map(a => getLimitedData(a, keys));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do like this two by saperating `objectFunction` and `ArrayFunction` recursively**

```js
 

let keys = ['age', 'work', 'main', 'description', 'type', 'date'];

     let response = {
        users: [
            {
                user_id: 1661871600,
                details: {
                    height: 150,
                    age: 33,
                    work: 1015,
                    school: 10,
                    degree: 933
                },
                work: [
                    {
                        id: 500,
                        main: 'Doctor',
                        description: 'Ofto',
                        icon: '10d',
                    },
                ],
                look: {
                    all: 100,
                },
                transport: {
                    speed: 0.62,
                    max_speed: 349,
                },
                visibility: 10000,
                hair: {
                    type: 0.26,
                },
                date: '2022-08-30 15:00:00',
            },
            {
                user_id: 324235256,
                details: {
                    height: 110,
                    age: 25,
                    work: 101,
                    school: 110,
                    degree: 553
                },
                work: [
                    {
                        id: 500,
                        main: 'Software',
                        description: 'Programmer',
                        icon: '11d',
                    },
                ],
                look: {
                    all: 2,
                },
                transport: {
                    speed: 1.2,
                    max_speed: 49,
                },
                visibility: 221,
                hair: {
                    type: 5.6,
                },
                date: '2021-01-30 12:00:00',
            },
            {
                user_id: 12353743,
                details: {
                    height: 10,
                    age: 75,
                    work: 1,
                    school: 114,
                    degree: 3
                },
                work: [
                    {
                        id: 500,
                        main: 'Pension',
                        description: 'Architect',
                        icon: '1d',
                    },
                ],
                look: {
                    all: 6,
                },
                transport: {
                    speed: 3.2,
                    max_speed: 29,
                },
                visibility: 21,
                hair: {
                    type: 1.6,
                },
                date: '2020-01-30 12:00:00',
            },
        ],
    };
// main function
const fun =(ob, k , con)=>{
    // recursive object function  
     const objectFun =(arr)=>{
         for(y in arr){
         if(typeof arr[y] === "object"){
            objectFun(arr[y])
          }else if(Array.isArray(arr[y])){
            arrayFun(arr[y])
          }else if(k.includes(y)){
           temp[y] = arr[y]
          }}}

     // recursive array function
     const arrayFun =(xx) =>{
          const usersList = ob[xx].map((ar, i)=>{
          objectFun(ar)
          con.push(temp)
          temp ={}
          })}

      // main access key for in loop
    for(x in ob){
        var temp = {}
         arrayFun(x)
    }
       return con
    }
    console.log(fun(response , keys , []))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```